# PyQt5 QWebEngineView Crashes When setGeometry is Removed

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have this basic PyQt5 app with a single `QWebEngineView` widget.  If I remove the `self.setGeometry(0, 0, 950, 750)` line, then the app crashes.  I get a message saying that Python has stopped responding, and I have to force close the app.  Why is that line required?  Calling `self.showMaximized()` causes the `QWebEngineView` to take up the entire screen, so the dimensions are changing anyways.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget


class UIExample(QWidget):
    # Setup a signal to trigger updating the graph

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # Initialize the GUI
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setHtml(
            """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>HTML5 : Hello World Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p>
            Hey there!
        </p>
    </body>
</html>"""
        )

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Example QWebEngineView")
        # Note: Removing setGeometry causes the app to not respond
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 950, 750)
        self.showMaximized()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = UIExample()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here are the PyQt5 package versions I have installed:

```
PyQt5==5.15.7
PyQt5-Qt5==5.15.2
PyQt5-sip==12.11.0
PyQtWebEngine==5.15.6
PyQtWebEngine-Qt5==5.15.2
```

Comment: What OS? Have you tried to run the code in a terminal or command prompt to see if you get more output before the crash? Btw, `QVBoxLayout(self)` already sets the layout on `self`, calling `self.setLayout(layout)` is unnecessary.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on arch-linux (qt-5.15.5, qt5-webengine-5.15.10). Assuming you're testing on ubuntu, are those the official packages, or did you install them via some other means? It's also unclear which line is actually causing the problem. What happens if you comment out `showMaximised`, and use `setGeometry` with `show` instead?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10. It doesn't matter if I use show() or showMaximised().  The issue occurs if I do not call setGeometry but does not occur if I do call setGeometry

Comment: @cvanbeek So, it seems to be a platform-specific bug in qt5 and/or qt5-webengine. Assuming you're using the latest versions available on your platform, you can try downgrading (or testing with pyqt6) to see if the problem persists. There doesn't seem to be anything related to "setgeometry qwebengineview" on the [qt bug tracker](http://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa). You would need debug versions of all the relevant libraries to obtain more useful information from the crash - but that's going to hard to set up on Windows.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you for the info.  I'll probably just ignore it for now since I can get around it by calling `setGeometry()`.